# Explain what each row does in the r code

Tags: r

I have this code here:

```
  S <- nrow(inputs) # number of samples
  if(J*K!=S) stop("The number of samples does not equal J times K")
  D <- ncol(costs) # number of decision options

  nb <- lambda*effects-costs
  baseline <- max(colMeans(nb))
  perfect.info <- mean(apply(nb,1,max))
  evpi <- perfect.info-baseline

  sort.order <- order(inputs[,input.of.interest])
  sort.nb <- nb[sort.order,]

  nb.array <- array(sort.nb,dim=c(J,K,D))
  mean.k <- apply(nb.array,c(2,3),mean)
  partial.info <- mean(apply(mean.k,1,max))
```

I have used this and it produces me the correct output let's say, but since i'm new to the statistical part behind this, i can't actually understand what it does.

Could someone please explain what each row means?
I'd appreciate that.

I went searching each function, but it gets complicated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some general hints to understand you code:

1. create small version of your objects: inputs, costs,effects ( see `??sample`,`??matrix`)
2. put a `browser` in the beginning of the code and go through it step by step, each time you see how the variable are modified.
3. read the help of functions if you cna't guess what is done from the transformation: `??colMeans`,`??apply`,...